# Meteor Spiderable not returning full content?

Tags: meteor

The following is my current code, 
https://github.com/daslicht/kiss

After cloning it to my server I have added the spiderable package 
and added phantomjs to the $PATH.

The basic structure of my app is essentially a Master Details layout, 
on the left we have a list of headlines(Master) 
and on the right the according details to each Headline.

So far so good..., when I call one page with:

```
http://78.47.126.11:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=blog/SbZayHyqKmZhCEHme/1
```

I get my Headlines displayed but not the according Details.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong ?

Currently it is running as bundle with forever.

Best Regards
Marc

Answer (score 0):

If think the Spiderable package won't show stuff from MongoDB, only static template-stuff.

So in this example only the static stuff will show, not the DB-loop:

```
<template name="main">

   {{> thisWillBeOutputted}}

</template>

<template name="thisWillBeOutputted">

   <h1>This will be displayed, sweet!</h1>

   {{#each thisLoopFetchesStuffFromDBAndWontShow}}

      <!-- stuff in this loop won't be displayed :( -->

      <p>Something which won't be displayed: {{dbDoc.something}}</p>

   {{/each}}

</template>
```

**To summarize (what I believe is correct):**
The Spiderable package better than not displaying anything for bots (which is the case with vanilla-meteor), but it's not as good as a good-old-PHP/whatever-site.

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your problem. What I would do is add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your head instead of going with the escaped-fragment thing. More here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

I'm still pretty sure your DB-stuff won't get picked up by Google though. But I could be wrong!

Comment: The headlines are also saved in MongoDB and they show up (try to add one :), so that can't be the issue. I totally agree that server- side rendering is much better for being indexed. Thank you very much for taking the time to write me an answer !

Comment: Oh, I missunderstodd your problem. Have you looked at it in Webmaster Tools though? I'm pretty sure google won't see DB-stuff.

Comment: According to the Meteor Documentation it should be pick up any content, since it will be just returned as rendered html which is rendered using PhantomJs
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot

Best Example:
http://tinyurl.com/o8vuneu

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, your app is ignoring 'blog/SbZayHyqKmZhCEHme/1'.
The error is because:
 https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/487

> The spiderable package does not currently reattach the escaped
>   fragment back onto the url sent to phantomjs, so it's not possible for
>   the page to display the correct content.
>
> For example if googlebot encounters a url:
>
> ```
> http://domain.com/#!page
> ```
>
> It will make a request from the server:
>
> ```
> http://domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page
> ```
>
> However at the moment, the spiderable package will call phantomjs with
>   the following url:
>
> ```
> http://domain.com/
> ```

My solution is to create your own spiderable package with fix by 'https://gist.github.com/4096777'